# Non-Negative and Sparse LDA?

Tags: classification, pca, discriminant-analysis

I am wondering if the concept of Non-Negative and Sparse Linear Discriminant Analysis exists? I recently found an algorithm for Non-Negative and Sparse Principal Component Analysis (on which the PC loadings cannot be negative), and I would like to have the same approach for Linear Discriminant Analysis. 
Do you know an research article describing such algorithm ?
Do you know an R package implementing this concept ?